# Using MergeMap with SwitchMap to result from NgRx Store

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have 3 selectors:

1. `getUserInfo` => to fetch acnt details (sample output : `{acntId: 'A1'}`)
2. `getAllDepartments` => to fetch list of all dept Ids (sample Output: `['d1','d2']` )
3. `getAllDeptManagers` => to get list of dept managers for each Dept Id.

Now, I have written below code:

```
 this.store
        .select(getUserInfo)
        .pipe(
          switchMap((res) => this.store.select(getAllDepartments, { account: res.acntId})),
          mergeMap(deptId => this.store.select(getDepartmentManagers,{departmentId: deptId }))
        )
        .subscribe((depts) => {
          console.log(depts);
        })
    );
```

As per my understanding, `mergeMap` takes array and accordingly call a `function` and flatten the array of observable which is returned.

I am getting  `['d1','d2']` in every call to selector `getAllDeptManagers` . what I am expecting is `d1` and then `d2` and so on, and then get all response in one go as `depts` of console.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mergeMap` doesn't flatten the output from its inner Observable. It just reemits when the inner Observable emits and that's it. So it looks like you want to use `forkJoin` here:

```
mergeMap(deptIds => forkJoin(
  deptIds.map(deptId => this.store.select(getDepartmentManagers, {
    departmentId: deptId
  }).pipe(take(1)))
)),
```

Then observers will receive a single array of results for `deptIds` because `forkJoin` will wait until all of the inner Observavbles complete.

Comment: Hello, I do not get response in .subscribe block once I implemented this

Comment: Try adding `.pipe(take(1)` for each source Observable

Comment: Or, for better readability (and in case you're sure that at least one item is emitted), `.pipe(first())`

Comment: @martin : I would be grateful if you can guide me for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500500/combining-multiple-conditional-observables-for-preparing-the-data . Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to map your array into a stream. The first `switchMap` takes a value and maps it onto a stream. That stream emits an array, so you just need one more `mergeMap`. Like this:

```
this.store.select(getUserInfo).pipe(
  switchMap(res => this.store.select(getAllDepartments, { account: res.acntId})),
  mergeMap(depIdArr => depIdArr), // <- The extra bit
  map(deptId => this.store.select(getDepartmentManagers,{departmentId: deptId })),
  // Really, your source observables should be competeing, 
  // but if they don't take(1) should ensure that they do.
  mergeMap(depMan$ => depMan$.pipe(take(1))),
  toArray()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

That mergeMap looks funny *(the extra bit)*, but if you return an array it gets converted into a stream. It's semantically the same as `mergeMap(depIdArr => from(depIdArr))` but it's a bit more performant.

If turning an array into a stream and back into an array is too much, you can combine those steps with `zip()`, `combineLatest()`, or what might be best in this case: `forkJoin()`

```
this.store.select(getUserInfo).pipe(
  switchMap(res => this.store.select(getAllDepartments, { account: res.acntId})),
  map(deptIdArr => deptIdArr.map(
    deptId => this.store.select(
      getDepartmentManagers,{departmentId: deptId }
    )
  )),
  // Really, your source observables should be completing, 
  // but if they don't take(1) should ensure that they do.
  map(deptIdArrS => deptIdArrS.map(
    deptId$ => deptId$.pipe(take(1))
  ),
  mergeMap(deptIdArrS => forkJoin(deptIdArrS))
).subscribe(console.log);
```