# Combining multiple conditional Observables for preparing the data

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have two `stores` which I need to prepare the combined data

1. To get all departments (for ex 50 departments)
2. To get all users (ex: `1000` users)

I want to merge both the data and prepare final data. **Note:** the department would require all users to be loaded (which might take some time), and obliviously, `users` can't do anything on their own as they need `department` data to prepare the final result.

Here is for `department`:

```
      this.store.select(getUserInfo).subscribe((info) => {
        this.store.select(getAllDepts).subscribe((depts) => {
          if (depts.length < 1) {
            this.store.dispatch(loadDeptStore({ accountId: info.acntId}));
          } else {
            console.log(depts);  // get Dept data
          }
        });
      })
```

for `Users` data I have:

```
      this.store
        .select(getUserInfo)
        .pipe(
          flatMap((info) => {
            this.acntName = info.acntId;
            return this.store.select(getAllUsers, { accountId: info.acntId });
          })
        )
        .subscribe((res) => {
          if (res.length < 1 ) {
            this.store.dispatch(loadUsersInAccountStore({ billingCrmAccountId: this.acntName }));
          } else {
            console.log(res); // get users data
          }
        })
```

Shall I use `combineLates` or something else, if so, how should I do it in reactive way using RxJS features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't make a subscription in a subscription, it's an anti-pattern. Always use higher observables. I don't know exactly how the code work since I don't use ngrx but you could build your observables like that:

```js
    const userInfo$ = this.store.select(getUserInfo);
    userInfo$.pipe(
        mergeMap(info => {
            this.acntName = info.acntId;
            const departments$ = this.store.select(getAllDepts)
                .pipe(
                    map(depts => {
                        if (depts.length < 1) {
                            return this.store.dispatch(loadDeptStore({ accountId: info.acntId}));
                        } else {
                            return depts;  // get Dept data
                        }
                    })
                );
            const users$ = this.store.select(getAllUsers, { accountId: info.acntId })
                .pipe(
                    map(res => {
                        if (res.length < 1 ) {                          
                            return this.store.dispatch(loadUsersInAccountStore({billingCrmAccountId: this.acntName }));
                        } else {
                            return res; // get users data
                        }
                    })
                );
            return combineLatest([departments$, users$]); 
        }),
        map(([depts, users]) => {
            // do stuffs and return something
        })
    ).subscribe(res => console.log('results: ', res));
```

CombineLatest will emit when both your observables have emitted once. It will emit again each time one of the observables emits.
It may not work with your current implementation but you get the idea on how to combine two observables from one source.

Comment: My instinct when combing sources that are only meant to emit once is to use `forkJoin()`. Its semantics are tighter since you know the source observables have completed - which means if you do something else wrong, you'll fail early rather than create a memory leak which can be frustrating to find later.

Comment: It goes the other way when you expect it to emit but it does not because one of your observable doesn't complete but you don't understand why ;). You should always unsubscribe anyway and you can use a take(1) to complete your stream. As long as you know what you are doing, both lead to the same end result.

Comment: If one of your sources doesn't complete and you don't understand why, then your application will fail. You will not get any results until you've resolved the problem. :)  With `combineLatest` you might have a program that works just fine but is actually leaking memory. You'll get more and more active observables that are not completing and just eating up RAM. You may have 1000s of lines of code and it might be very hard to figure out what is causing the memory leak. But yes, take(1) will work as well!

Comment: You may not want your observable to complete right away. How do you get updated values if you shut your stream right away? Just use promises at this point. It depends what you need as a developer. Leaving an observable open is stupid anyway. Always unsubscribe.

Comment: If you're **not** combining sources that are meant to emit just once, then forkJoin() is no longer your best bet. It's about using the best tool for the job. Promises aren't lazy and don't have any first-class ways to cancel them. Plus, switching between Obsverables and Promises complicates your code as you compose different sources. Furthermore, composition is also why you may not know ahead of time when/how a stream needs to be unsubscribed. Including that information once you know (via the right operator like `takeUntil`, `forkJoin`, ect) adds semantics to your application.

Comment: I tkink we got the idea. We have tools, we use them right. We are not helping the answer by playing this "nitpicking game" . Op knows what to do at this point.